# How to show Power Point in iOS

Tags: ios

What the best way to show a power point file ( ppt or pptx ) apart from UIDocumentInteractionController or QLPreviewController?

The problem with UIDocumentInteractionController or QLPreviewController is they don't show the ppt properly or similar than the Office app.

Comment: Your only other options is to use `UIWebView` which will use the same render as QLPreviewController. These are your options unless there is some thirty party library. But asking for then is offtopic.

Comment: I would accept a third party library as answer :)